# Spring boot register bean when application is started

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Before a Spring boot application starts, I need to make a request for some credentials. I'm storing them in an object.

Is there a way to register this object as a bean before all other beans so that I can inject them in a configuration class?

I've tried like below but it's throwing exceptions:

```
SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, 
SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class BeanOnInitApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Starting the app");

        MongoCredentials creds = makeARequestToExternalServiceAndGetCredentials();
    
    
        GenericApplicationContext appContext = (GenericApplicationContext) SpringApplication.run(BeanOnInitApplication.class, args);
        appContext.registerBean("mongoCredentials", MongoCredentials.class, () -> creds, bdc -> bdc.setLazyInit(false));
    }

}
```

And config class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    MongoCredentials mongoCredentials;

    @Bean(name = "mongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate mt() {
        String url = "mongodb://" + mongoCredentials.getUsername() + ":" + mongoCredentials.getPassword() + "@localhost:27017/admin";
        MongoDatabaseFactory mdf = new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(url);
        return new MongoTemplate(mdf);
    }
 }
```

If this is not a solution what are the alternatives? The scope is to register a critical bean before anything else.

Comment: Just make that call in an `@Bean` method that produces the `MongoCredentials`. That way it will just work.

Comment: @M.Deinum For my scenario it will not. Getting the credentials is mandatory. How the initialization will behave if the request fails (due to network or other issues)? It will initialize mongoTemplate with null. What if I want to add a retry mechanism: to not do anything until I have the credentials? In the latter scenario, can I add a wait loop until success inside a bean?

Comment: You could implement your retry logic within that bean function. And if there is any error, your Application should not start at all.

Comment: No it won't initialize with null. Throw an exception and the application won't start. You can do whatever you want to produce the bean. Basically all you want already will work if you just make it a bean (and implement a retry with for instance spring retry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it an `@Bean`.

```java
@Bean
public MongoCredentials mongoCredentials() {
  return makeARequestToExternalServiceAndGetCredentials();
}
```

Don't handle exceptions in the `makeARequestToExternalServiceAndGetCredentials` and just let them bubble up. If the request then fails the application will simply fail to start. If you want to retry wrap the call with a Spring Retry `RetryTemplate` and you have everything you want.

Another option is, which would allow for using auto configuration for Mongo as you appear to be using Spring Boot. Is to create an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` which loads the properties and adds them to the environment.

```java
public class MongoCredentialsPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
 public     void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
  MongoCredentials credentials = makeARequestToExternalServiceAndGetCredentials();
  String url = "mongodb://" + mongoCredentials.getUsername() + ":" + mongoCredentials.getPassword() + "@localhost:27017/admin";

  Map<String, Object> props = Map.of("spring.data.mongodb.uri", url);
  MapPropertySource mps = new MapPropertySource("mongo-credentials", props):
}
}
```

Finally you could also modify your current code to do the same as the `EnvironmentPostProcessor`.

```java
SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class BeanOnInitApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Starting the app");

        MongoCredentials creds = makeARequestToExternalServiceAndGetCredentials();
      String url = "mongodb://" + mongoCredentials.getUsername() + ":" + mongoCredentials.getPassword() + "@localhost:27017/admin";
        
        SpringApplicationBuilder sab = new SpringApplicationBuilder(BeanOnInitApplication.class);
         sab.properties(Map.of("spring.data.mongodb.uri", url)).run(args);
    }
}
```

With both the latter and the `EnvironmentPostProcessor` you should be able to use the mongo autoconfiguration (which will provide the `MongoTemplate` for you.

Comment: I liked the last approach. thanks